# faster and more effective way changing date format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list of users of which I want to change the Date format.

```
public class UserData
{
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
}

private void FormatDateResult(List<UserData> users)
{
    foreach (var v in users.ToList())
    {
        if (v.DateAdded != null)
        {
            string temp = v.DateAdded.ToString();
            DateTime dAdded = DateTime.Parse(temp);
            v.DateAdded = dAdded.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

With allot of users it tends to be a bit sluggish. How can I do this in a better way?

Comment: Why would someone store `DateTime` as a string?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `ToList()` can be intended, though. Imagine a concurrent thread which changes an original list while `foreach` iterates. The loop would throw an exception. `ToList()` creates a copy of the original list and prevents this. But `ToList()` is absolutely redundant if the list is used in a single-threaded manner.

Comment: Side note: I suspect that `DateTime? DateAddedUtc;`  would be much more appropriate representation of optional Date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this looks better

```
public string DateAdded { get; set; }
public string FormattedDateAdded => DateAdded != null ? DateTime.Parse(DateAdded).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") : DateAdded;
```

then you can use `UserData.FormattedDateAdded` anywhere you want

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: @kienct89 I suspect he can, but he's too impish now for that:)